# How to remove the double quotes variable in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My project has different SQL Server DataTable. I will bind the data from user request table. so got table name as

Example:

```
table = "MyTable"
```

How to write the SQL query for select the particular table.

```
con.open();
SqlAdaptor da = new SqlAdaptor ("select * from '" + table.replace(""", "\"")" + '")
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My replace is not working so I hope to any one resolve my issue.

Comment: I smell SQL Injection

Answer (score 2):

Just escape `"` character?<sup>1</sup>

```
table.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

Also you don't need single quotes for your table name. By the way if you get this table as an input, I will strongly suggest do some strong validation before you put it in your query or use a whitelist.

You didn't show us rest of your code but use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and adapter objects.

1: <sub>Since it is an [escape sequence character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
SqlAdaptor da = new SqlAdaptor ("Select * from " + table.Replace('"',  ' ').Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string table = "MyTable";
table.Replace('\"', ' '); //Or
table.Replace('\"',string.Empty);
```